# Getting CS0246 when making ASP.NET-web application but MySql.Data is added

Tags: c#, asp.net, netbeans, mysql

First thanks for trying to solve my problem.

I'm making a webapplication with asp.net with C# in the background.
So when a user pushes the button on the login.aspx, the Administratie.login() is called upon with the login name and password. Administratie calls upon Database.cs to execute its own login() in  which it makes an connection to the database.

login.aspx:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace Admin_SiM.Forms
{
    public partial class login : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        private Adminstratie administratie;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            administratie = new Adminstratie();
        }

        protected void btLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string result = administratie.Login(tbEmail.Text, tbWachtwoord.Text);
            errorlabel.Text = result;
            if (result == "correct")
            {
                // go to next screen
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Administratie.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Services.Protocols;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Admin_SiM
{
    public class Adminstratie
    {
        private Database db;

        public Adminstratie()
        {
            db = new Database();
        }

        public string Login(string email, string password)
        {
            string result = db.Login(email, password);
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Database.cs:

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System;


namespace Admin_SiM
{
    public class Database
    {
        MySqlConnection con;

        public Database()
        {
            string constring = "server=127.0.0.1;uid=root;pwd=obsessed;database=sim;";
            try
            {
                con = new MySqlConnection(constring);
                con.Open();
            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                string errormessage = ex.StackTrace;
                Console.WriteLine(errormessage);
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }

        }

        public string Login(string username, string password)
        {
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select wachtwoord from admin where mailadres = '" + username + "';", con);
                MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                string ww = "";
                try
                {
                    ww = reader.GetString(1);
                    if (ww == password)
                    {
                        return "correct";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return "incorrect wachtwoord";
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    return "invalid email";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return "error";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run it, I just get this message:
http://nl.tinypic.com/r/2zoda2h/8
thus saying that it cannot find the namespace of Mysqlconnection giving errorcode CS0246.

I do however have added all mysql references I could find:
http://nl.tinypic.com/r/2qasm02/8

But when delete all references except MySql.Data, I get the errormessage earlier at the "using"-part

Can someone please help me? I tried all the solutions I could find online but none of them seem to work since most of them just tell me I should add the reference or reinstall the connector. But I already did those things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP here.
I found the answer:

You need to add reference to `MySql.Data.dll` but it is better you can add this dll as package by using NuGet

below is the Package Manager Console command

```
PM> Install-Package MySql.Data
```

So I went to tools > Library Package Manger > Package Manager Console.
I then used the above command.